# why this dictionary unpacking is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

the following code works:

```
>>> stack = ['a','b','c']

>>> top, *stack = stack

>>> top

'a'
>>> stack

['b', 'c']
```

but why this doesn't work?

```
>>> dict1={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

>>> x, **dict1=dict1

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

shouldn't I expect x={'a':1} and dict1={'b':2, 'c':3}?

Comment: dictionaries are not sorted, so having `x` first doesn't really mean anything

Comment: A list of strings, unpacked, gives individual strings, not sublists. If it was really parallel, an unpacked dict would give individual key-value entries, not subdicts. However, ``a': 1` is not a valid type in Python. Fortunately, there's an easy way to get pairs from a dict: `x, *rest = dict1.items()` works, as does `(k, v), *rest = dict1.items()`. (Note that, as njzk said, order is not guaranteed). It is better to be explicit, and `v = dict1.get('x')` (or `pop`, if you want it out of the dict).

Comment: @Amadan except you'd have no guarantee that `x` would contains `(a, 1)` rather than any other key-value pair from the dictionary

Comment: @njzk2: why can't x be assigned whatever the first from unpacking dict1?

Comment: @techie11 because a dict doesn't have a notion of `first`, since dicts are not sorted

Comment: @njzk2: `OrderedDict` is sorted, and yet it still doesn't allow that. Rather, dicts iterate like `dict.keys()`, yielding a sequence of keys; you can use `*`, but not `**`.

Comment: @njzk2, Amadan: Thank you very much!

Comment: @njzk2, AFAIK, from python3.5 dictionary is ordered. Is that correct?

Comment: @SaifulAzad Dics are ordered by default in Python 3.7

Comment: dict have been insertion-order sorted since 3.6 as an implementation detail, and officially since 3.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use dictionary unpacking, you can do something like this: (Using Python3.7)

```
>>> dict1={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> x, *dict1=dict1.items()
>>> x
('a', 1)
>>> dict1
[('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

`dict1.items()`, returns a list of tuples where each tuple contains 2 elements, in the form of `(key, value)` pair. Hence, if you wish to convert the unpacked values back into a dictionary, you'll have to do something like this ->

```
>>> x = [x]  # x = list(x),  won't work for you, because it converts tuple into a list.
             # What is actually want is the tuple to be an element of the list.
>>> x        # And it works like a charm! 
[('a', 1)]
```

But, when the list of tuples was unpacked, `dict1` contains a list of length 2, both of which are tuples. Hence, to convert it into a dictionary is a fairly straightforward approach.

```
>>> dict1
[('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> dict1 = dict(dict1)
>>> dict1
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the operator `**` can be only used to unpack a dictionary into keyword arguments in a function call. For example you can merge two dicts with the function `dict()` that has `**kwargs` as parameter:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
b = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}

print(dict(**a, **b))
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

You can’t use the double star in tuple unpacking like the single star.